# Strange Error Message in Visual Studio 2017 (Extensibility Project)

Tags: vsix, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS 2017 RC (64 Bit, Windows 10 V. 1607) and tried to start a simple VSIX project (mainly following Mads Kristensen's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFiRotBsVKU). I also installed Extensibility Tools.
When I try to add a CommandClass, I am getting an error message telling "The parameter is incorrect. E_INVALIDARG" (see image below).
[image]

The project fails to compile bringing the following compiler error message: "No resource file set the resource merger.  MyFileName". 
And, strangely enough, if I open the VSCT file, which is an XML, it does not look like XML (no XML markup) and any attempt to open it with the VS's XML editor only looks like a text file.
I failed to find a hint in the web; does anybody know the recipe?

Comment: Any weird extension you may have had added which tries to provide a buggy XML editor?

Comment: @Ray Koopa. Don't think so. Anyway, my question was in February, it is no longer actual. Somehow I was able to produce a couple of working VSIX'es since then.

Comment: My conjecture to this and similar topics is that the installed extensions do not march hand-in-hand with the VS upgrades coming too often. Even the most well-known and simple extensions like Build Version Increment sometimes refuse to work altogether with a new VS upgrade, but, with the next one, they do again. This is my observation and I find it, I must say, annoying.